# When do I need to use a $ to refer to a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, variables

For example, in my code sometime I do

```
$var
```

and sometimes I just do

```
var
```

Here is a more concrete example:

```
upstream() {
    push server_shared_shortname
    ssh $server_shared -t "cd  ~/public_html; git pull -q ~/root.git master"
}
```

Comment: `push server_shared_shortname` invokes the `push` command (whatever that is; did you mean `git push`?) with the literal string `server_shared_shortname` as its argument. Is that what you intended? When do you "just do `var`"?

Answer (score 5):

`$var` is for a variable *expansion*: you use it when you want Bash to substitute in the *value* of the variable. So, for example, this:

```
var=foo
echo "$var"
```

sets the variable `var` to the value `foo`, and then runs the command `echo foo`.

---

**Edited to add** a few things:

- `$` also has some other related uses; for example, `$( ... )` runs the command `...`, capturing its output, and expands to that output (minus trailing newlines), and `$(( ... ))` evaluates the arithmetic expression `...` and expands its result:

  ```
  cat $(echo foo)      # equivalent to:  cat foo
  cat $((2+3))         # equivalent to:  cat 5
  ```
- As codeforester alludes to below, you don't actually need the `$` to expand a variable in "arithmetic expressions" (where everything is interpreted as a number), such as are found in `(( ... ))`, `$(( ... ))`, `let ...`, array indices, and the right-hand-side of variable assignments when the variable has been declared as an integer variable.
- *The Bash Reference Manual*, at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html, is detailed and of high quality. It can take a bit of mental adjustment to start thinking the way that Bash does, but it's worth it IMHO.

Comment: better question is when do I need to use quotes?

Comment: When there are spaces within. Ex: echo $(command arg1 arg2) .

Comment: @brannonteer - see this post to understand when to use quotes around variables in shell [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @M.Becerra: Not just spaces -- and your example doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: "when do I need to use quotes" is a _different_ question, not a "better" question. More relevant here is "when should I use braces with my $" like `${var}` vs `$var` (`${var:-"bar"}`)

Answer (score 3):

- **On *assigning*** to a variable, you **do *not* use the `$` prefix**; e.g. `var=1`

  - This also applies to assignments in the contexts of variable-declaring builtins `declare`, `local`, and `export`.
- **On *referencing*** a variable (its value) you ***do* use `$`**; e.g., `echo "$var"`

  - As an ***exception*, there are *arithmetic contexts* in which you can and generally *should* reference variables *without* the `$` prefix** - see below.

    - Do note that this exception **applies only to variables whose values are / can be interpreted as *integers*** (Bash only supports integer arithmetic).
  - As in the example above, **you should *typically* *double-quote* `$`-prefixed variable references (expansions)** to prevent unwanted modification of the resulting value by the shell by way of its [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), notably by splitting the value into multiple arguments by whitespace (word-splitting) and interpreting the value as a filename pattern (globbing).
  - Using the **form `${...}`** (curly braces around the name / expansion expression) is necessary in the following cases:

    - **Disambiguate the variable name** in (expandable) strings where characters immediately follow the variable name that Bash would otherwise consider part of the variable name; e.g., `echo "${HOME}grown"`.
    - **[Parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)** that *transform* the expanded value, such as by prefix and suffix trimming, string replacement, or substring extraction; e.g., `echo "${HOME%/*}"` yields something like `/home`, with the shortest suffix (`%`) matching pattern `/*` getting trimmed from the value of `$HOME`; in other words: the last path component is removed.

---

**Arithmetic contexts**, in which integer[-interpretable] variables generally need *no* `$` prefix:

- ***Explicit* arithmetic contexts**:

  - `$(( ... ))` (**arithmetic *expansion***; a POSIX-compliant feature)

    - `echo $(( var ))` prints `1`, the value of `$var`.
  - `(( ... ))` (**arithmetic *expression***; a Bash extension)

    - Used **as a conditional**: `(( var )) && echo 'yes'` prints `yes`, because value `1`, the value of `$var`, interpreted (conceptually) as a Boolean, is (conceptually) true.
    - Used to **assign the result of a calculation to a variable:**
      `(( sum = var + var )); echo "$sum"` prints `2`<sup>[1]</sup>
- ***Implicit* arithmetic contexts (all of which are Bash extensions)**:

  - Inside **array indices**:

    - `arr=( one two ); ndx=0; echo "${arr[ndx+1]}"` yields `two`
  - Inside **substring / array-slicing operations** (index and offset):

    - `str='one'; ndx=0; echo "${str:ndx+1}"` yields `ne`
    - `arr=( one two three ); ndx=0; echo "${arr[@]: 0: ndx + 2 }"` yields `one two`
  - Inside **`[[ ... ]]` with *arithmetic* operators**:

    - `[[ 1 -eq var ]] && echo 'yes'` yields `yes`.
  - **Assignments to *variables declared with `declare -i` or `local -i`*, which marks them as integers**:

    - `declare -i sum; sum=var; echo "$sum"` yields `1`
    - `declare -i sum=1; sum+=var; echo "$sum"` yields `2`

*Caveat*: Typically, it doesn't matter whether you reference variables in these contexts with or without the `$` prefix - but there are subtle differences; in short, **use the `$` prefix in arithmetic contexts *only* in the following case**:

- You need a *nonzero default value* that you provide via a *parameter expansion*; e.g., `${var:-2}` defaults to `2` if `$var` is unset or empty.

---

<sup>[1] `(( ... ))` has an older equivalent, the obsolescent `let`.

`(( ... ))` is preferable, because it doesn't require quoting and is more easily recognized as being related to

`$(( ... ))` (as well as being visually more distinctive).

Compare `(( sum = var + var ))` to `let 'sum = var + var'`</sup>